# Why Type III ANOVA is used for this analysis of coefficients

Tags: self-study, anova, linear-model

Note that I'm giving (what I believe) is minimal information to solve this problem. If more details than what are provided here are needed, please let me know, and I can provide them.

I have a model
$$y_{ij} = \alpha_i + \beta x_{ij}+\epsilon_{ij}\text{, } \quad\epsilon_{ij} \overset{iid}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)\text{,}$$
where $i = 1, 2, 3$ and $j = 1, \dots, 30$. $x_{ij}$ is an observed quantitative variable, and everything else ($\alpha_i, \beta$) are constants. The conditional mean of $y_{ij}$ (conditioned on $x_{ij} = x^{*}$)  is $\mu_i = \alpha_i + \beta x^{*}$, and I would like to test the hypothesis $$H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_3$$
against $$H_1: \text{ at least one of the above isn't equal to the others}\text{.}$$

This is obviously an ANOVA problem. I'm asked to calculate a $F$-statistic for this hypothesis test and to specify the degrees of freedom.

I'm given a Type-I table starting with the $x_{ij}$ variable in the first row, and the $y_{ij}$ variable in the second row, and a Type-III table with the same structure. I have the solution to this problem available, but do not understand it.

The idea is this: $$F = \dfrac{MS_{x\text{ variable}, \text{Type III}}}{MS_{\text{Error, Type I}}}\text{.}$$
Why is this?

I understand that $MS_{x\text{ variable}, \text{Type III}}$ is different from $MS_{x\text{ variable}, \text{Type I}}$ in that the Type III somehow (?) takes into account the $y_{ij}$ variable into account already (something to do with a quadratic form involving the difference of the projection matrices), as opposed to in the Type I (where the quadratic form would just include the projection matrix created by the design matrix with just the $\alpha_i$ terms).

Hopefully not everything I've said here is gibberish. I've done my best to explain the general problem, and if any more details are needed, I can provide them.

Comment: Type III contrasts, which are maximum variance contrasts in some situations, are generally discouraged.  See the classic discussion by Bill Venables at http://sedarweb.org/docs/wsupp/S10RD01.pdf.

Comment: @FrankHarrell This isn't for my own analysis. It is a question from a qualifying exam. Nevertheless, thank you for the article.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Sorry to spam you about this, but I thought I recognized the name! Your regression text is great, and I plan to read it in-depth this summer.